# Run the same Delphi app on two machines, one immediately returns "Resource TfrmHSMain not found", the other runs fine

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-5

`TfrmHSMain` is the name of my main form.  The machine where it isn't running is my development machine, Windows 10 Pro 1909.  Where it is running OK is a Windows Server 2012.

What can I look for to explain why my app simply won't run without an error on my development machine?

This is a recent issue, only started happening within the last few months, but I've been able to work around it by running on the other machine.  However, it's starting to get annoying, and although it seems to inconvenience no one but me, I'm not satisfied with the workaround, and I need to know what is happening.

It is exactly the same executable copied to two places.  When the error occurs, it is within seconds of loading the application.  I have inserted logging, and last line that loads successfully is `Application.CreateForm(TfrmHSMain, frmHSMain);`  I put a logging line as the first line of the form's Create method, and it never reaches there.

Comment: What happens if you create another Windows user account on your development machine and try to run the app there? What if you change the windows language of that user account?

Comment: Are you experiencing this problem only in this specific application? Or does it happen even with new projects? If it is happening only with your application are you perhaps adding some additional resources to your application manually by including other RES files?

Comment: You didn't told us if the application works within the IDE nor if you tried with the debugger. Since it doesn't work on your development machine, you should be able to use the debugger to understand where it fails. Before your form is created, all initialization sections of all used units are executed. Maybe one is failing for some reason on your own computer. You can single step the initialization sections by running your program with F7 (not F9) and using F7 again. Select "use debug .dcus" in the project options.

Comment: Cannot debug the application, even though we own the source code for this, because the IDE is on a virtual Windows XP box that is effectively air-gapped from the network due to OS security concerns, and the application is a database application that needs the network to function.  I have tried using Process Monitor from SysInternals (now Microsoft) to determine what is being searched for when it fails on the Windows 10 box, but the output is to noisy, and I don't know what to look for.

Comment: @NineBerry, your suggestion produced results!  I created a different user, logged in, and no error!  Any ideas as to why?  So I can clean up my main user account?

Comment: @SilverWarior, It is only happing with the main application that we write ourselves in Delphi, haven't tried creating any other apps to see if I can replicate with a test case.  We do a minimal amount of RES file handling, even dealing with limited Localization internally (not the best way, for sure, but it works for us.)

Comment: @fpiette, thanks for the idea, but due to security constraints, we can't use the IDE on the source box to test the code.  The source box is virtualized, so I copy the app to my Win10 box for testing, which is where the error is happening.  If I do a second copy to a Win2k8 box, it works fine.  And, as I've now found, if I run as a new user under my Win10 box, it also works fine.

Comment: @DanielBragg No need to install the IDE: use the remote debugger.

Comment: @fpiette, Never had much luck with the remote debugger, but honestly, I haven't tried using it over 15 years.  There is no network between the IDE and my Windows 10 box.

Comment: @DanielBragg Manage to have a network! The Windows 10 box has a network (You said that), to connect another computer (Laptop?) having the IDE installed to that network and use remote debugger. Or let the problem as it is, hoping it will solve by itself.

Comment: I am in the process of creating a new User Profile, because NineBerry's solution did work, but I'm concerned that unless I can find out why my profile is failing, when I re-add all of the configuration that makes my current profile functional, that it'll fail again.

@NineBerry, can you please add your comment as an Answer, so I can work with it?

Comment: Do the two user accounts use different language settings? If yes, look into that. If no, use the tool "Process monitor" by Microsoft to track what files your application accesses before it fails.

Comment: Only use English for all of my profiles.  I have tried using Process Monitor, but it surfaces a firehose of information, and not knowing exactly what to look for is difficult.  However, I will try to capture ProcMon sessions, and do a Diff between a Pass/Fail, in the hopes that a clue may surface.

Comment: Look at the files your process accesses. The list shouldn't be too long. Ignore the other information like registry access and everything by other processes

Comment: Is TfrmHSMain in the main executable or in some package? What happens when you rename the executable file on your system?

Comment: @NineBerry, OH, Good call.  Renaming the executable avoids the problem.  That means there's something in Win10 that is blocking the app (or portions of the app) based on its filename.  Once we nail this down, I need you to post and answer, so I (and many others) can give you credit for this!

Comment: Look for a file with the name starting with the same original name as the executable file in the search paths of the windows user.

Comment: There is now no executable with the exact same name on my machine (all have been renamed) and still the error occurs.  Could this be a part of Windows 10 SmartScreen, where it's matching the name to some rule, and performing some OS-specific manipulation?